# fiber template for eventual game engine

Tags: c++, templates, game-engine

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <functional>

template<std::function<typename ...Args>>
class dvTFiber {

private:
      std::function<Args... args> Run = nullptr;
};
```

Hey everyone longtime lurker though this is my first question as I cant quite find what I'm looking for anywhere on the internet.

I'm sure its kinda obvious what I'm trying to do from the code itself. A template for a fiber class that can take any kind of std::function<> pointer as a type. I'm trying to do something similar to what Naughty Dog's 2015 GDC presentation about using fibers to keep multi core, multi threaded systems working without any downtime, and id did with their idTech 7 engine on Doom Eternal. Though I dont nearly expect those kind of results by myself I just wanted to see if i could do it.

Anyway I'm not too familiar with Template programming. I learned programming through C and still haven't fully caught up with c++14 let alone c++20 and meta programing with templates. hell I'm still working on reflection in my build pipeline with libClang.

Sorry for the history lesson on me. Long story short I'm wondering if what I'm trying is either A) Possible, B) easily Possible and I'm just overthinking it, or C) Some combination and I'm just an idiot

any help, even if its just to call me an idiot, will be incredibly helpful and appreciated thank you soo much in advance

Comment: `std::function` isn't a pointer, so you can't initialize `Run` with `nullptr`; you can make `Run` a pointer to `std::function`, so `Run = nullptr` works, but I suspect is better if you maintain `Run` as a `std::function` and initialize it empty, so `std::function<Args... args> Run{};`

Comment: `template<std::function<typename ...Args>>` is not valid code. It's not clear at all what your trying to do and what the issue is.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do either. Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/541T6EExe) something close to what you want?

Comment: I thought I explained it. I'm trying to make a template that will take a std::function ptr, yes i forgot to type that when I was writing this question also forgot the return type, so no matter what arguments or amount of arguments a function has so I dont have to write ten thousand different versions of my Fiber Class for each function in the engine, again I apologize as my code is probably not easy to read as I constantly forget syntaxes and hell simple things all the damn time.

Comment: I found the talk on the GDC Vault if anyone is interested in watching as I'm apparently not very good at explaining.. anything really not just this https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022186/Parallelizing-the-Naughty-Dog-Engine

Comment: @TedLyngmo YES! Thank you! A Million times Thank You! I thought I was gonna have to go plan B and just make them all VOID pointers and wrap them in lambdas

Comment: @MatthewHinnerichs You're welcome :-) I don't really know how to write a good answer for it though since I was merely guessing away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If you were worried about how you wrote you're answer just look at my question again. lol. the minute I posted it I realized I got the std::function syntax wrong, forgot the return type ENTIRELY.

Comment: @MatthewHinnerichs That happens. :-) Hope it works out!

Answer (score 0):

The template syntax is wrong. If you want to send many arguments to the private function type, you'll have to send them directly, not through the `std::function` type:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct dvTFiber {

   // ...    
private:
    std::function<void(Args...)> Run; // by default is a null function.
};
```

And use it like this:

```
auto fiber = dvTFiber<int, bool, float>{};
```

Now if you also want to allow different return type, you can also send it as the first parameter:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct dvTFiber {

private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> Run;
};
```

Also,

> A template for a fiber class that can take any kind of std::function<> pointer as a type

There's no pointer to `std::function<>` in this code, only plain `std::function` in this code.